# Get value of Codemirror text area in angular

Tags: angular, codemirror

I am trying to inegrate codemirror with angular2. Editor is diplaying properly, how can i get the editor value on button click? I am new to angular.

**app.component.html**

```
<codemirror [(ngModel)]="code" [config]="config"></codemirror>
<div [innerHTML]="code"></div>
<button type="button" name="run_test" class="btn btn-danger" 
(click)="runTest()">Run tests</button>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({     
  selector: 'app-selector',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class CourseComponent implements OnInit {
code: string;
codeConfig = {
                mode: 'htmlmixed',
                lineWrapping: false,
                lineNumbers: true,   
                gutters: ["CodeMirror-lint-markers"],
                lint: true
             };
      ngOnInit() {
          this.code= "<h1>Hello</h1>";
      }

    runTest()
   {
      //how to get value here
      //console.log(this.code) gives "<h1>Hello</h1>"
   }
}
```

Comment: @Vega runTest is in component class only. I tried with this.codeToDisplay, but it s giving assigned value only. If we change content in editor, then also its giving old value only.

Comment: I don't see `codeToDisplay` in your html, you are using `[(ngModel)]="code"`

Comment: @yurzui  Updated :)

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: i followed this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-codemirror.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/4tNsupvjNqFatUPYu8dn?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui thanx for your effort. I understood the bug. There was other bug hemce did not get the value. Thank you again..